# SimpleMembership changing username

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, simplemembership

I'm using SimpleMembership in an MVC4 app and need the ability for a user to change their own username.

I have the functionality working, so when a user changes their username it works.  However when invoking things like Roles.IsUserInrole() then it fails as User.Identity.Name is set to what they logged in as, not the new value.  That value no longer exists in the database, as they have changed their name.

I can't see a method to update the logged in user context with a username.  For the most part I can store the users ID in session and retrieve it when doing queries, but I'm using the Roles method to display data in a view which fails.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

This is my current (working) solution:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit(AccountEditModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (HasSensitiveInformationChanged(model)) // model.EmailAddress.ToLower() != User.Identity.Name.ToLower()
            {
                if (Membership.ValidateUser(User.Identity.Name, model.Password)) // && WebSecurity.IsCurrentUser(User.Identity.Name)) //redundant?
                {
                    using (UsersContext db = new UsersContext())
                    {
                        UserProfile user = db.UserProfiles.FirstOrDefault(u => u.EmailAddress.ToLower() == User.Identity.Name.ToLower());

                        if (user != null)
                        {
                            user.EmailAddress = model.EmailAddress;
                            db.SaveChanges();
                            WebSecurity.Logout();
                            WebSecurity.Login(model.EmailAddress, model.Password);
                            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Search");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Could not find user. Please try logging in again.");
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("","Could not change email address. Please verify your password and try again.");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //no change
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Search");
            }
        }

        return View("Index", model);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't think you were able to change the username field (would be nice if you could show me how you achieved that).

The only solution I see is that you force the user to log off after changing the username, so when they log back in they will have the correct User.Identity.Name.

Comment: You can also request the user to enter the password when the user changes the username, it enhances security, plus this means that you can log the user out and right away log them back in (see David's answer for an example), so the session account info will be correct.